# Configure MariaDB client with host-specific credentials?

Tags: mariadb, client, mariadb-10.2

How can I configure my MariaDB client (`mysql`) so that I don't have to enter a password to connect, regardless of which host I am connecting to?

I can't just put a password in the `[client]` section of `~/.my.cnf` because that would apply all hosts.

For example, I'd like to be able to connection with `mysql -h myhost mydatabase`, ie. without specifying username or password. Even better would be the ability to specify a "host alias" instead of the actual (awkwardly long) hostname.

It sounds like this is possible in MySQL with the [mysql-config-editor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) but MariaDB [does not have this feature](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_config_editor-compatibility/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `~/.my.cnf` make sections like:

```
[clientmy_host_name_1]

[clientmy_host_name_2]
```

Then make an alias (assuming Linux-like OS - depending on shell, you can perhaps put the alias in `~/.bashrc_local`):

```
alias mysql="mysql --defaults-group-suffix=\`hostname --short\`"
```

Now you can connect without specifying the password to any of the hosts for which you have stored the credentials in `~/.my.cnf`. (These would be *my_host_name_1* and *my_host_name_2* in my example above.)

Comment: Clever. A bit awkward, but it meets my needs. Thanks.

Comment: sounds similar to the answer below, very similar.

Answer (score -3):

I have used the mysql_config_editor years ago it works, very well. And it is an option for you. other options will be to create some alias as long as you are using linux/mac:
something like
alias mysqlserver1='mysql -ulalala -plalalapass -hserver1'

Comment: As I said in my question, AFAICT [MariaDB does not include `mysql_config_editor`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_config_editor-compatibility/). If you assert otherwise, please cite your source(s).